# Access method's local variable in Angular unit test with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can I access the `type` variable inside `validate` function? The problem is `code-covarage` shows that `type` in `if` statement not covered and I dunno how can I cover that.

```
interface NotUnique {
    notUnique: boolean;
}

@Injectable()

export class CheckExists implements AsyncValidator {
    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

    async validate(control: FormControl): Promise<NotUnique> {
        try {
            if (!control || !control.parent) {
                return;
            }
            const value: string = control.value;
            const type = value.includes('@') ? 'email' : 'username';
            if (type) {
              const res = await this.http.post('/users/exists', {field: type, value: value}).toPromise();
              if (!(res as ExistsResponse).exists) {
                  return null;
              }
              return { notUnique: true };
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

upd: image[image: screenshot of code-coverage]

Comment: Since that variable is local to the function, there is no way to access it inside a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

If code-coverage is not covering `if(type)` that means your test is always returning from:

```
if (!control || !control.parent) {
   return;
}
```

In your unit test, you should fill the test data in such a way that it reaches till `if (type)` statement. That will happen if you make sure that `control` variable have proper data in it and has data in `control.value` too.

Comment: added an image and updated question. returns from the second if statement are covered with tests

Comment: @slxvxBatih Try putting `if(type !== null) {` instead of `if(type){`